# How to checkout/clone only working directory (Latest SRC snapshot) in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

How to checkout/clone only working directory (Latest  SRC snapshot)  in  mercurial,
and not the entire repository(history and all).

i know it against the dvcs philosophy, but is it possible ??
If so how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have local access to the repository, you could use the [`hg archive` command](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#archive).

If you want a snapshot of a remotely hosted repository, it depends on the used web interface and its configuration. For instance [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) allows you to download packages of specific revisions. Mercurial's standard web interface (the one you see when running `hg serve`) [also has this functionality, if enabled](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Create_links_to_snapshots_of_files_and_tarballs).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the usual web frontends to Mercurial repos have the option to download a tarball of a specific revision. This is not always enabled, but widely available. As an example, the [current tarball](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/archive/tip.tar.gz) of the Mercurial repo itself.

Instead of the hash, any symbolic revision (tag or branch name) can be specified.

Comment: But note that it is not a clone, or a checkout. You can't commit and push changes back to the repository, but it doesn't sound like the OP wants that either.